# R memory issue with memory.limit()

Tags: r, memory-management

I am running some simulations on a machine with 16GB memory. First, I met some errors:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6000.1 Mb (the number might be not accurate)
```

Then I tried to allocate more memory to R by using:

```
memory.limit(1E10)
```

The reason of choosing such a big number is because `memory.limit` could not allow me of selecting a number less than my system total memory

```
In memory.size(size) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

After doing this, I can finish my simulations, but R took around 15GB memory, which stopped my from doing any post analysis.

I used `object.size()` to estimate the total memory used of all the generated variable, which only took around 10GB. I could not figure where R took the rest of the memory. So my question is how do I reasonably allocate memory to R without exploding my machine?
Thanks!

Comment: are you sure you've looked at all existing variables? Does `ls(all=TRUE)` only list the ones you generated? Note that even if an object is deleted, the memory used to store that object isn't free until the garbage collector is called. R does this periodically, but you can force collection with `gc()`.

Comment: I have not checked the memory usage for all of my memory. But I did use gc() in my simulation after each iteration...

Comment: In general, you need about 3 times the amount of memory your objects occupy. This is because of copying of objects.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra: It means the usage of memory for my R session is normal? Any suggestions on how to optimize it? Thanks

Comment: One solution I often use is to perform the analysis in chunks, e.g. first one half of the data and than the rest. Alternatively, buy more RAM.

Comment: Have you tried memory profiling? http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rprofmem.html

Answer (score 2):

R is interpreted so WYSINAWYG (*what you see is not always what you get*). As is mentioned in the comments you need more memory that is required by the storage of your objects due to copying of said objects. Also, it is possible that besides being inefficient, nested `for` loops are a bad idea because `gc` won't run in the innermost loop. If you have any of these I suggest you try to remove them using vectorised methods, or you manually call `gc` in your loops to force garbage collections, but be warned this will slow things down somewhat

The issue of memory required for simple objects can be illustrated by the following example. This code grows a `data.frame` object. Watch the memory use before, after and the resulting object size. There is a lot of garbage that is allowed to accumulate before `gc` is invoked. I think garbage collection is problematic on Windows than *nix systems. I am not able to replicate the example at the bottom on Mac OS X, but I can repeatedly on Windows. The loop and more explanations can be found in [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) page 13...

```
# Current memory usage in Mb
memory.size()
# [1] 130.61
n = 1000

# Run loop overwriting current objects
my.df <- data.frame(a=character(0), b=numeric(0))
for(i in 1:n) {
this.N <- rpois(1, 10)
my.df <- rbind(my.df, data.frame(a=sample(letters,
this.N, replace=TRUE), b=runif(this.N)))
}
# Current memory usage afterwards (in Mb)
memory.size()
# [1] 136.34

# BUT... Size of my.df
print( object.size( my.df ) , units = "Mb" )
0.1 Mb
```